# Energy Saver preferences keep breaking

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, preferences, plist

This is a new question related to a question I asked previously.

[MacBook is sleeping despite being set to "never" sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30416/macbook-is-sleeping-despite-being-set-to-never-sleep)

Basically, the MacBook would sleep after 3 hours despite the preferences telling it to "never" sleep.

I fixed the original problem by deleting the Energy Saver plist file.

However, after two weeks, it broke again and the original problem came back.  I have no doubt that I can just fix it by deleting the preference file again.

Obviously something external is botching up the Energy Saver preference file.  I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how I can determine what could be causing this problem in the first place.

**EDIT:**

Trashing the Energy Saver plist file no longer fixes this issue.  I've removed Caffeine and I'm out of ideas.  I can't even effectively troubleshoot this since it takes three hours just to see if it will sleep or not.  What else can I do?  Where else can I look?

Comment: Do you use any applications that manipulate sleep settings? Such as Caffeine or InsomniaX?

Comment: @JasonSalaz, I have Caffeine installed but have not used it within the last few weeks, maybe not for a month or more.  AFAIK, Caffeine only prevents "Display Sleep" and my issue is with System Sleep.  You're thinking that Caffeine maybe is corrupting the plist file?

Comment: I don't imagine Caffeine is corrupting anything if you're not actually using it. It was just an idea that came to mind.

FYI, Caffeine prevents any/all sleep, not just display sleep.

Comment: @JasonSalaz, I trashed the prefs file again and updated Caffeine to the latest version.  It went to sleep again last night though.  I'm getting pretty frustrated with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try resetting the SMC, as described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

Comment: I ended up deep cleaning all the caches as well as your suggestion of resetting the SMC.  Last night, it finally stayed awake.