# Mac mini set to never sleep, but seems to be sleeping anyway (does not respond to network)

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, mac-mini

I've enabled SSH into my mac mini (late 2012 running OS X 10.9.3), and have the energy saver settings set so that the display sleeps after 10 minutes, and the computer is set to never sleep.

If the mac goes unused for a while, then I try SSH into it, the SSH connection is refused. If I go bang on the keyboard or mouse to wake up the mac, then the SSH connection is accepted and it works.

This appears as though the mac is ignoring my energy saver settings and is in fact sleeping when it shouldn't be.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is there anything to look for in console to verify if it is actually sleeping?

Thanks

Comment: The advice for this question may be helpful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30416 In particular, what does the output of `pmset -g` say? If that looks OK, try `pmset -g everything` to look at the power management history of your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you rebooted after saving those energy settings. I've had the same problem and only ever found a work-around: [caffein] (http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) will keep your computer from going to sleep (I believe later versions have the ability to let he monitor sleep while keeping the CPU itself active). This may be slightly more convenient in that you only need to click the menu bar icon to let it sleep rather than opening up energy settings all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the Console.app and search all of the logs for 'sleep'. It looks like the most interesting items are from the kernel log. You will find entries that give the reason for the sleep:

```
6/20/14 7:42:38.000 AM kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
```

You might also search for 'wake' to see if there is any info about why it is not waking on network activity.

Unfortunately, Apple does not appear to publicly document what the sleep cause numbers mean. From my searches, it appears that 5 means that sleep was caused by low battery, but in looking at my own logs, I am not sure that this is accurate.

This pervious question explored what is know about [sleep numbers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere) but has no definative answer.

You might take a look at the command line `pmset` which allows you to control and view various power management options some of which are not directly accessible via the GUI.